# FireFox "No video with supported format and MIME found."

Tags: html

I have a website that displays MP4 videos from the server. Below is the HTML code I'm using with PHP:

```
<video autoplay width="616" height="420" controls>
<source src="' . $site . 'uploads/videos/' . $f . '" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Now, the problem I'm going through is that:

1) The videos display normally on my FireFox without any issues.
2) On some other FireFox browsers, the videos do not play and users get a message saying "No video with supported format and MIME found."

Any idea?

I found some people saying that it is a server issue. But if it is a server issue, then how come it works on my browser?!

Thanks

Comment: MP4 support is quite recent in Firefox. You should consider adding an alternative source in the webm format. I'm assuming the other foxes are somewhat older versions. :)

Comment: what value `$site` contains?

Comment: @Zword $site contains a string of the domain name 'http://www.sitename.com/'

Comment: @MildyInteresting Thanks for that. Is there a way to automatically generate webm files after uploading mp4 files?